# How to translate this

Tags: wordpress, language-translation

In a theme I use I have this line:

```
$msg = .__('Error! ', BUNCH_NAME)
$lang['required']           = __("The %s field is required.", BUNCH_NAME);
```

How do I translate the strings 'Error! ' and "The %s field is required." into another language?
I tried putting them as is into my po file, translate them and compile into mo but that did not give any result.

Comment: You shouldn't use constants such as `BUNCH_NAME` as the domain, but a literal string. [See here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2).

Comment: the page you provide uses a variable as well. anyways, the code provided is from a theme. If it was $msg = .__('Error! ', 'themedomain') how would I translate it?

Comment: It does show an example, saying it is incorrect. There's 3 tools underlying WP's i18n: [xgettext](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xgettext.1.html) to generate the `.pot` template by analyzing source files (doesn't understand PHP constants); the `.pot` is copied to a `.po` for manual translation and this is then compiled to a `.mo` file using [msgfmt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/msgfmt.1.html); finally [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)) to do runtime translation. Try the [Loco Translate Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) - works pretty easy.

Comment: you are right. However using a variable will only interfere in automatic parsing of the theme's files for translation. So i should be able to add translations to the po files myself in some way. since i dont want to change the template because of support i am looking for the 'how to' to get the text translated